Unexpected behavior when selecting text in C# WinForms WebBrowser
I created a WinForms application using .NET Framework 4.5.2. When I select certain text in the WebBrowser control and change the active window, the selection does not turn gray, but simply disappears. When I click back into the application window, the selection appears for a few milliseconds and then disappears. However, if I select text, change the active window, and then press any  in the document, the selection appears again.
I suspect that instead of turning gray, the selection turns transparent.
Selected text in WebBrowser
Selection disapeared after clicking out of window
WebBrowser properties
I tried to solve the problem using ChatGPT, but it didn't help. I tried to manually control the text selection using the Activated and Deactivate events, but it did not give the expected result

UPD
Solved partly by adding Deactivate and Resize events
private void MainWindow_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Focus();
}
private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        _maximizeAfter = true;

    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal && _maximizeAfter)
    {
        _maximizeAfter = false;
        ReportBrowser.Focus();
        FailedBrowser.Focus();
    }
}

To make selection gray I will add a JS scripts to events and hope it will work  ;)

.NET Framework version 4.5.2 is no longer supported and the WebBrowser control is out of date.
